# SSH forced pseudo-terminal dimensions

Tags: ssh, terminal

I am in the unfortunate position of having to automatically use an interactive program via SSH. Obviously, there won't be a terminal available, but luckily SSH allows me to force it to allocate a pseudo-terminal with `-tt`.

This works great so far. However, the interactive program I am using changes its output depending on terminal size - allowing for pagination.

My question now is: Can I somehow influence the size of the pseudo-terminal allocated? I'd rather not deal with the pagination and would much prefer to simply present a pseudo-terminal large enough to display everything at once.

Comment: your program should have some option to not use pagination..

Comment: @Jakuje It doesn't, but your comment still helped. It has an option to ignore the terminal length and use a specified one! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Xandaros have you found a solution? my terminal after run `ssh -tt` has no minimal height